# Array JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Haciendo un juego de preguntas y respuesta en JavaScript inspirado en el Juego "Ahora caigo" he intentado generar de forma aletoria asteriscos dentro de una respuesta que se encuentra asociada a una pregunta, para así darle mayor aleatoriedad al juego. Para ello he guardado las respuestas y preguntas en un array de clave valor, posteriormente después de seleccionar la pregunta de forma aleatoria convierto la repuesta en un array para poder sustuir carácteres por *. El problema es que a la hora de mostrar el array en un archivo html o por consola a este se le suman una coma después de cada carácter. He intentado convertirlo a String pero aún así el problema persiste.

```js
const difficulty = 0.5;
    const QUESTIONS = [

        {
            question: '¿Cúal es la biblia de los programadores?',
            answer: 'Clean Code'
        },
        {
            question: 'Archipiélago conocido como las afortunadas',
            answer: 'Islas Canarias'
        },
        {
            question: '¿Cúal es la capital de España?',
            answer: 'Madrid'
        }, {
            question: 'Mejor lenguaje de programación',
            answer: 'Vanilla JavaScript'
        },
        {
            question: 'Periférico que en inglés recibe el nombre de "mouse"',
            answer: 'Ratón'
        }
    ]

    function generateRandomNumber(minValue, maxValue) {

        let randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue)
        return (randomValue);
    }


    let randomQuestion = generateRandomNumber(0, QUESTIONS.length)

    function game(){


        let asociatedAnswer = QUESTIONS[randomQuestion].answer;
        asociatedAnswer = Array.from(asociatedAnswer);
        let characToReplace = Math.round(asociatedAnswer.length * difficulty);

        for(let index = 0; index < characToReplace; index++){

            let randomIndex = generateRandomNumber(0, asociatedAnswer.length)
            asociatedAnswer[randomIndex] = "*";
            String(asociatedAnswer);
        }

        document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = ( "Pregunta: " + QUESTIONS[randomQuestion].question + "  -  Respuesta asociada:   " + asociatedAnswer);

      
    }
```

Agradezo cualquier aportación, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

```
function game(){
let asociatedAnswer = QUESTIONS[randomQuestion].answer;
asociatedAnswer = Array.from(asociatedAnswer);
let characToReplace = Math.round(asociatedAnswer.length * difficulty);

for(let index = 0; index < characToReplace; index++){

    let randomIndex = generateRandomNumber(0, asociatedAnswer.length)
    asociatedAnswer[randomIndex] = "*";
    String(asociatedAnswer);
}
var palabraConPistas = "";
for(var i = 0; i < asociatedAnswer.length; i++){
    palabraConPistas = palabraConPistas + asociatedAnswer[i];
}
alert(palabraConPistas);
    document.getElementById('question').innerHTML = ( "Pregunta: " + QUESTIONS[randomQuestion].question + "  -  Respuesta asociada:   " + palabraConPistas);
}
```

En tu función game() recorre el arreglo de como quedó al final asociatedAnswer y el valor de cada posición lo concatenas en una variable nueva y esa variable nueva la muestras al final, de igual forma puedes decidir si quieres poner espacios de esta forma palabra = palabra + " " + asociatedAnswer[i]

Answer (score 1):

Le hice unas pequeñas modificaciones a tú código y por último terminé con un join(), para unir el array en un string,

```js
const difficulty = 0.5;
const QUESTIONS = [

    {
        question: '¿Cúal es la biblia de los programadores?',
        answer: 'Clean Code'
    },
    {
        question: 'Archipiélago conocido como las afortunadas',
        answer: 'Islas Canarias'
    },
    {
        question: '¿Cúal es la capital de España?',
        answer: 'Madrid'
    }, {
        question: 'Mejor lenguaje de programación',
        answer: 'Vanilla JavaScript'
    },
    {
        question: 'Periférico que en inglés recibe el nombre de "mouse"',
        answer: 'Ratón'
    }
]

function generateRandomNumber(minValue, maxValue) {

    let randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxValue - minValue) + minValue)
    return (randomValue);
}


let randomQuestion = generateRandomNumber(0, QUESTIONS.length)

function game(){
    let asociatedAnswer = QUESTIONS[randomQuestion].answer;
    asociatedAnswer = Array.from(asociatedAnswer);
    let characToReplace = Math.round(asociatedAnswer.length * difficulty);
 
    asociatedAnswer.map((dato,index)=> {
     let randomIndex = generateRandomNumber(0, asociatedAnswer.length)
     asociatedAnswer[randomIndex] = "*"
   })
   let resultAnswer = asociatedAnswer.join('');
    
   console.log( "Pregunta: " + QUESTIONS[randomQuestion].question + "  -  Respuesta asociada:   " +resultAnswer);


}

game()
```

Saludos!